# Excel VBA Emails, occasional errors occuring

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

The code throws an occasional Run-time error '424': Object required.

The spreadsheet contains a person's first name in column "C", email addresses in "BG" column; Outlook emails are generated when an error value in "AO" column is >=3 AND if there is an empty cell in "AU" column. For the loop to close, a date stamp is inserted into the "AU" column.

The code is at the Sheet level. This generic sheet is supposed to serve as a template for month's worth of data; i.e. copied 12 times/year into the same workbook.

Any advice on how to eliminate the error messages? Thank you in advance.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'This code cycles through each row and looks for an email address in "BG" column.
'If found and recipient "C"'s 'Total Error Occurences' "AO" value is >=3, an email is generated for a display.
'To close the loop on each row, a date is entered into 'Date Email Generated' "AU".

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("BG").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Cells(cell.Row, "AO").Value >= 3 And _
           IsEmpty(Cells(cell.Row, "AU").Value) = True Then _

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Test E-mail"
                .Body = "Dear " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "This is a " & vbNewLine & _
                        "test email." & vbNewLine & _
                       vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Signature"

                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Display  'Or use Send
            End With

            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing

            With Cells(cell.Row, "AU")
                .Value = Date
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
            End With

        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *Exactly* where is the error occuring?  Commenting out the error handlers will help identify the problem.

Comment: `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` gets highlighted

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the Sub creates a Compile error: Expected End Sub.

Comment: Every time your user changes a cell in the worksheet your code will create an Outlook application. If there are a lot of changes then this could get messy. I suggest you put the line `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` in a module where OutApp is a global and then refer to it in the worksheet change event.

Comment: `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` should work fine as long as Outlook is installed.  AntiVirus maybe ?

Comment: Does [this page](http://www.devhut.net/2014/10/31/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/) help? Could it be a VBA library reference is needed?

Comment: Thank you everyone. Library reference is there. Robin made me think about the inefficiency in the code. I wasn't able to refer to another module, yet, but I moved the `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` under the If statement.

Comment: `For Each cell In Columns("BG").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Cells(cell.Row, "AO").Value >= 3 And _
           IsEmpty(Cells(cell.Row, "AU").Value) = True Then _

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0) `

Answer (score 0):

Try using existing instance, or else creating a new instance if one is not already running,

```
Dim MyApp As Boolean
Dim OutApp  As Object
Dim OutMail  As Object

'// Open or Start a new instance of Outlook
On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MyApp = True
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
'// then Create an Outlook Mail Item
```

Or see nice `Function StartOutlook` example from [Daniel Pineault Click here](http://www.devhut.net/2014/10/31/createobjectoutlook-application-does-not-work-now-what/)

```
Function StartOutlook()
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    Dim oOutlook        As Object
    Dim sAPPPath        As String

    If IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application") = True Then    'Outlook was already running
        Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    Else    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        sAPPPath = GetAppExePath("outlook.exe")    'determine outlook's installation path
        Shell (sAPPPath)    'start outlook
        Do While Not IsAppRunning("Outlook.Application")
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    End If

    '    MsgBox "Outlook Should be running now, let's do something"
    Const olMailItem = 0
    Dim oOutlookMsg     As Object
    Set oOutlookMsg = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)    'Start a new e-mail message
    oOutlookMsg.Display    'Show the message to the user

Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Function

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox "The following error has occured" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Source: StartOutlook" & vbCrLf & _
           "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
           , vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "An Error has Occured!"
    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
End Function
```